# Opportunity Delete Unit Test Failed

Tags: unit-test

When I run this test unit, it fails and the error message is
System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0064D000004yFkTQAU; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Opportunities can not be deleted: [] Can anyone help, should I use a try,catch exception?

```
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (after delete, after insert, after undelete, after update, before delete, before insert, before update) {
    try {
        map<Id, Opportunity> sendVOCS = new map<Id, Opportunity>();
        map<id, Opportunity> stageChanged = new map<Id, Opportunity>();

        if (trigger.isAfter) {
            system.debug('OpportunityTrigger isAfter');
            if (trigger.isUpdate) {
                system.debug('OpportunityTrigger isAfter isUpdate');
                for (Opportunity record : trigger.newMap.Values()) {
                    Opportunity oldMapMatch = trigger.oldMap.get(record.Id);
                    if (record.StageName != oldMapMatch.StageName) {
                        // Voice of Customer Survey criteria
                        if (record.StageName == 'Closed - Awarded' || record.StageName == 'Closed - Lost') {
                            sendVOCS.put(record.Id, record);
                        }
                        // add newMap opportunity to a id/opp map
                        stageChanged.put(record.Id, record);
                    }
                }
                // send voice of customer surveys if they should be - criteria is above
                if (sendVOCS.keySet().Size() > 0) {
                    SendMail sendMail = new SendMail();
                    sendMail.SendVoiceOfCustomerSurvey(sendVOCS);
                    system.debug('Send Voice of Customer Surveys');
                }
                if (stageChanged.keySet().Size() > 0) {
                    StatusAndStageLogging statusAndStageLogging = new StatusAndStageLogging();
                    statusAndStageLogging.logOpportunityStage(stageChanged, trigger.oldMap);
                    system.debug('Log Opportunity Stage');
                }

             if(Trigger.isDelete) { // verify for delete operation
                for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.Old) {
                  opp.addError ('Opportunities can not be deleted');
               }
             }            
            }
        }
    }
    catch (exception e){
        ErrorHandler error = new ErrorHandler();
        error.logError(e);
    }
}


@isTest
private class Test_OpportunityTrigger {

    static testMethod void stageChanged() {
        Market_Segment__c mk = new Market_Segment__c(Name = 'Automotive');
        insert mk;
        Account account = TestUtils.CreateAccounts(1)[0];
        account.Market_Segment__c = 'Automotive';
        insert account;
        Opportunity opportunity = TestUtils.CreateOpportunities(1)[0];
        opportunity.AccountId = account.Id;
        opportunity.Amount = 2000000;
        insert opportunity;
        opportunity.StageName = 'Closed - Awarded';
        update opportunity;
    }
@isTest
      static void PreventOpptyDelete(){
      Market_Segment__c mk = new Market_Segment__c(Name = 'Automotive');
      insert mk;
      Account account = TestUtils.CreateAccounts(1)[0];
      account.Market_Segment__c = 'Automotive';
      insert account;
      Opportunity opportunity = TestUtils.CreateOpportunities(1)[0];
      opportunity.AccountId = account.Id;
      opportunity.Amount = 2000000;
      insert opportunity;

      delete opportunity;
      }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should I use a try,catch exception?

When you're trying to test code that throws an exception, or causes an exception to be thrown through Validation Rules or `addError()`, you should catch that exception and make assertions to validate that the right exception was thrown for the right reason.

Here's the way I like to do that.

```
Boolean caught = false;
try {
    delete opportunity;
} catch (DMLException e) {
    System.assert(e.getMessage().contains('Opportunities can not be deleted'), 'exception message');
    caught = true;
}

System.assertEquals(true, caught, 'expected exception thrown');
```

Your test will then allow any other exceptions to go through and produce a failure.

Comment: thanks David it worked.

Answer (score 2):

This chunk of code of your trigger doesn't allow you to delete the opportunity.

```
 if(Trigger.isDelete) { // verify for delete operation
    for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.Old) {
    opp.addError ('Opportunities can not be deleted');
    }
 }
```

Comment: No validation rule, there is a Opportunity Trigger with that error message on

Comment: so what does this trigger do and why is your second test method called "PreventOpptyDelete()"? Which action does prevent opp from removing?

Comment: I edited the original post to show the trigger

Comment: I've updated the answer as well

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to get my unit test to pass instead of fail. And I think method 2 in the test unit is causing the issue

Comment: just wrap "delete opportunity"  in try/catch block, catch an exception and assert it.